# ArcGIS Pro: Split function deleting entire line

Tags: arcgis, esri

I've tried to split a line using the split feature which just deletes the entire line. I was then advised to Explode it but it says that "Explode only supports multipart geometries".

Does this mean that the line in question is singlepart?

Any ideas on how I can split this line?